# Close the agm-info-window when mouse clicked out of the info-window in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-google-maps

I'm working with angular-google-map.when marker is clicked info-window will open and hides previos window when other marker is clicked.now I want to close the info window when mouse clicked on map .

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="styles" [disableDefaultUI]="false" [zoomControl]="true"
[scrollwheel]="false" [streetViewControl]="false" [fitBounds]="false" (zoomChange)="onagmZoomChange($event)">


     <agm-marker *ngFor="let c of markers; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow, i)" [latitude]="c.location_details_lat"
  [longitude]="c.location_details_lon" [iconUrl]="m.icon">
           <agm-info-window #infowindow [maxWidth]="320" >
                <div class="info-header">
                     <h2>add: {{ c.add }}</h2>
                </div>
           </agm-info-window>
           </agm-marker>
   </agm-map>
```

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for the mapClick event on the AgmMap that checks if you have an open info-window, and if you do, close it. Since you have already implemented a handler to have only a single info-window open, you probably have a variable holding the window that is open, something like:

```
private singleInfoWindow: AgmInfoWindow = null;
```

Your handler for the AgmMap mapClick event can close that infoWindow:

```
if (this.singleInfoWindow) {
    this.singleInfoWindow.close();
    this.singleInfoWindow = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use the `closeOnMapClick` property option on your instance of snazzy-info-window:

`[closeOnMapClick]= "true"`

This is taken from documentation of closeOnMapClick, where you can read further: https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#closeonmapclick